# Existe um padrão de documentação/comentários de software em ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, documentação, comentários

Estou liderando uma equipe de desenvolvimento em ReactJs com Node.Js, e estou com uma dúvida sobre como documentar ou comentar esse código para que ele seja agradável e fácil de ser lido por outros devs.

Ainda se comenta código? Desculpe a pergunta mais é que eu sou das antigas, Asp clássico e talz onde tudo era feito assim.

Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Já leu isso aqui: [Um guia para estilização React](https://github.com/pagarme/react-style-guide)

Comment: Se precisar para Javascript: [Guia Google de estilo Javascript](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

Comment: Específico para documentação [JSDocs](https://jsdoc.app/)

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o código em si, só é uma boa comentar caso seja uma função muito específica e que pode gerar alguma duvida para outro dev. Mas o ideal é que o código seja escrito da melhor forma possível para que outro dev consiga identificar o que ele faz apenas de bater o olho.

Já vi algumas bibliotecas de documentação de componentes, caso a empresa tenha um styleguide bem customizado, pode ser que esse tipo de ferramenta ajude bastante os dev`s. Já trabalhei com a Docz: [https://www.docz.site/] Bem prática, dinâmica e com bastante pull request`s da comunidade.

E acho que a parte, é importante ter uma documentação robusta a respeito da regra de negócios do produto para que os dev`s possam consultar quando necessário.